# How to redirect from .ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have node.js chat

chat.ejs

```
function remove() {
            $.get("<%= remove %>", function () {
            });
            //location.reload();

        }
```

chat.js:

```
roomRouter.get('/remove', function (req, res, next) {
    let user = req.session.user;
    if (!user) {
        res.status(401).redirect('/')
    }
    let name = req.param('name');
    roomController.remove(user, name, function (done, err, message) {
        if (done) {
            res.redirect('/chat');
            res.end();
        } else console.log(message);
    })
});
```

It doesn't redirect to '/chat', still the same page. `done` is true in this case. if I put `location.reload()` to .ejs, it doesn’t even go into the request processing function. Why?

Comment: I don't think it is suitable to use EJS template in JavaScript, it will mess thing up. I recommend you to seperate it into a JavaScript file.

Comment: is `roomController.remove` a function from a library ?

Comment: @Sven.hig no, it's my function, it works as it should, process comes to string wuth ```res.redirect()```

Comment: @are you trying to remove the user from "list" before redirecting to `/chat`??

Comment: @Sven.hig no, it removes chat room

Comment: do you successfully remove chat room , and the only issue is redirect? the reason i am asking is because if you are trying to pass `variables` from `ejs` back to ` node` is not gonna work